# Loan Calculator

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to Angular JS. I was trying to create a Loan Calculator with Angular JS and the prototype seems to work well.

I want to ask all Angular's guru, if there is a better way (using the framework) to write only a formula for both interest rate. Actually I'm doing this thanks to a function as follow:

```
function totalCalc(years, amount) {
    calc = (((amount * 9.9 * years) /1200)/12) + (amount / (years*12));
    $scope.total = currencyRround(calc);

    calc2 = (((amount * 12.5 * years) /1200)/12) + (amount / (years*12));
    $scope.total2 = currencyRround(calc2);
}
```

I was thinking to get this work with **ng-repeat**, defining interest's rates as follow:

```
$scope.interests= [
    {
        rate: '9.9'
    },{
        rate: '12.5'
    }
];
```

and then integrate the values in a forEach as follow:

```
angular.forEach($scope.interests, function(s){
    interest = s.rate;
}
```

but I haven't enough experience to think further...
Do you find this could be a good way to get things done?

Here is the JSFiddle with the "Prototype":
http://jsfiddle.net/645Xs/2/

Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <div class="item">
            <h1>Rata mensile in CHF:</h1>
            <h2 ng-repeat='rate in [9.9,12.5]'>
                {{rate}} = {{(((one * rate * (two / 12)) /1200)/12) + (one / two) | number:2}}
            </h2>
        </div>
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/645Xs/3/)

Comment: This solution is very interesting! But previously I linked the wrong version of the Prototype... the updated one is here: http://jsfiddle.net/645Xs/2/

Comment: Well, it's the same solution - create an array of interest rates and iterate them with `ng-repeat` like i did in the fiddle.